# How to remove a popover from an element

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I am assigning an angular-strap popover to an element within an AngularJs directive when a certain condition is present:

```
 var myPopover = $popover(element, { title: 'ERROR', content: ErrorMessage });
```

Once the popover is assigned I cannot find a way to remove it.   I tried assigning the popover again, with the trigger option set to 'manual', but that had no effect.  Any ideas?

```
 var myPopover = $popover(element, { title: '', trigger: 'manual' });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was incredibly simple, all I needed to do was call `myPopover.destroy();`    I was confused regarding the scope of the variable within the directive and did not grasp that it could exist as long as the form was instantiated and that it applied to the current element only.

The full section of the directive is:

```
            function showPopover() {
            if (!hasPopup) {
                pop = $popover(element, { title: 'ERROR', content: ErrorMessage });
            }
            hasPopup = true;
        }

        function removePopover() {
            if (hasPopup)
                pop.destroy();

            hasPopup = false;
        }
```